# Bridge to a used eth1 card without losing connection via that card

Tags: ssh, ethernet, bridge

How  can I set bridge between a real eth card on a remote machine without losing my ssh connection to that  machine.

I ssh into a  machine via  its eth1 iinterface. 172.168.40.2 255.255.255.0.

I want  to join eth1 to a  tun/tap device 'tun0'. How  can I  do this without bringing down eth1  and losing my  ssh connection.

```
tunctl -u root
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 tun1
brctl addif br0 eth1
```

Result,  connection will be  lost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Connect to the machine via a different interface.
2. Connect to the machine at the console.
3. Set up the bridge in the system's startup scripts (you didn't specify what sort of system) and then reboot.

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
tunctl -t tap0 ; brctl addbr br0 ; brctl addif br0 tap0 ; \
ip addr del 192.168.115.200/24 dev eth0 ; \
ip addr add 192.168.115.200/24 dev br0 ; \
brctl addif br0 eth0 ; ip link set dev br0 up
```

This is executed so fast that the connection didn't break (not even a LAN connection). Even safer would be to do this within screen (which I did first but which turned out not to be necessary). The safest solution would be (within screen, of course) to drop everything in the firewall during these commands. So insert after the first line (before ip addr del) `iptables -I INPUT 1 -j DROP` and add at the end (after ip link set) `iptables -D INPUT 1`

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same problem, but running first the `ip link set dev br0 up` command was enough to keep the connection.

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are remote and can not use a different interface than those involved in the bridge, you could create NAT or port forwarding with net-filter (iptables) or install a proxy between those networks.